# Record Application Execution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am testing the application in the debug mode under several conditions. Now I'm doing it by writing some of the states and executed functions on the piece of paper and then comparing the scenarios.

Does anyone know if there is any built-in functionality in VS2008 or any additional tool that could record the selected states and executed functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [TRACE and DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64yxa344(VS.80).aspx) directives of .NET.  It means you have to write some code into your application where you want to Record events or variable states but it will give you a customized level of detail that should be better than writing down the information on a piece of paper.

Any **DEBUG** statements will only be compiled into a Debug build while **TRACE** statements are available to both Debug and Release builds (depnding on the directive specified).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want are tracing, but if you are comparing which functions are executed, a profiler like Vtune might help.  It can generate a table of what functions were called and how often, or a call tree.     I believe VS2008 Professional or Enterprise comes with a profiler also, although I haven't used it.